# Visual Tab Missing From Editor

Tags: tinymce

The visual/ text tabs have vanished from tinymce.   I have tried everything I could find on the web and nothing has worked:

Deactivate theme
Deactivate all plugins
stop concatenation of scripts

debug-scripts (no errors)
no js errors in admin

Is there any DB setting which could be causing this?

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anyone else is having this problem, I've found that a pretty reliable way to get your visual editor tab back after upgrading to Wordpress 4.0 is:

1. disable all plugins
2. Change the theme to one of the defaults (e.g. TwentyFourteen)
3. Go to "my profile" and check the "disable visual editor" box.
4. Save
5. Go back to "my profile" and uncheck the "disable visual editor" box.
6. Save

Comment: I only needed to do steps from the third one, thank's a lot !

Comment: At first I thought this sounded kind of silly, but skipping to step 3 totally exposed the problem for me. When I looked at my profile before, the "disable visual editor" box was un-checked, so I figured things were fine. But attempting to check it and save exposed that I didn't have a "nickname" set, a required field, and it couldn't save. Turns out back when I started working on this site, I created my profile though a SQL query because we couldn't track down admin access, and the query I used must have been incomplete. What a crazy bug to track down!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the style was recently added for 'hide-if-no-js' to have a `display:none'` value. Unfortunately, Wordpress add's this hide-if-no-js class always when echo-ing out the div in `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`.

So this seems like a temporary bug to me. For now overwriting this bug with CSS like this should be fine I guess:

```
function fix_lost_text_visual_tab() {
    echo "<style>.wp-editor-tools.hide-if-no-js { display: block !important; }</style>";
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'fix_lost_text_visual_tab', 100 );
```